# How to pass array to method?

Tags: c#

I have a jagged array with questions and answers for a trivia game.

```
string[][][] levels = new string[15][][];
for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
{
    levels[i] = File.ReadLines("l" + i + ".txt")
                 .Select(s => s.Split('|')).ToArray();
}
```

I need to make the help option in other 4 diferent methods and I need to pass this array to the method.

I try using:

```
    public string HELP5050(string[] quest)
    {
       // string  a = "a" ;
        Console.WriteLine("");            
    }
```

But I get error: **Not all code paths return a value **
I know that I need to return something with:

```
  return;
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What do you want to return? Return that.

Comment: Or do not return anything with `void` keyword instead of `string`

Comment: But what to I put next to the return function?

Comment: Whatever you want to return.. Have you read a [basic tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) on methods yet?

Comment: If you're simply trying to get it compile, return `String.Empty`.

Comment: @USER1: please post some sample code of your `HELP5050` function. so that we can helpyou what you should return.

Answer (score 2):

Use [void](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb.aspx) in case don't want to return anything

```
public void HELP5050(string[] quest)
{
}
```